# less @import (reference) option doesn't work in dotless

Tags: asp.net, web-essentials, dotless

We're using dotLess successfully with our project, we have lots of LESS files and use LESS itself to pull together different component files with the @import command, which works fine. Example:

```
@import 'common/_type.less';
```

Additionally, we use the @import (reference) syntax to allow Visual Studio's Web Essentials plugin to correctly load references for intellisense etc. Example:

```
@import (reference) '../components/_animations.less'; // reference only
```

Unfortunately, dotLess seems to fail when these (reference) statements are included, resulting in the less handler returning an empty file, and no traceable exceptions.

Any ideas?

**Further info:**

So we do a lot of themeing, which uses variable files to establish colors etc we run through all our less files. So our top level less file accessed in the browser might look like this (say theme-blue.less)

```
@import '_variables-default.less'
@import '_variables-blue.less'
@import '_master.less'
```

_master.less then contains further imports to prevent duplication across the themes:

```
@import 'mixins/_vendor-prefixes.less';
@import 'mixins/_clearfix.less';
... etc
```

Then what we end up with is the less files themselves that contain the reference statements.

So clearfix.less might reference mixins in vendor-prefixes.less, and that's where the @import (reference) comes in useful for intellisense:

```
@import (reference) '../mixins/_vendor-prefixes.less'; // reference only
```

Comment: Your use case seems interesting -- are you doing a standard import somewhere else and then a reference import in the actual file to get IntelliSense? I'm asking because I'm working on the feature in question. :-)

Comment: Never occurred to me to do that -- did you know that `@import (reference)` is actually "intended" for using mixins and variables from `@import`ed files without outputting any unused rules from that file? Anyway, logically, if the file is already imported with a regular import, the reference import shouldn't do anything, so in your case it's all good. I'll try make sure to handle that in a way that doesn't incur an extra performance penalty in the upcoming implementation. :-)

Comment: yep - that's exactly why we're using it, and it's a nice sort of "documentation" for what dependencies each less file has (sort of like using statements). But the key thing is those (reference) statements allow Web Essentials to validate the entire less file, and provide intellisense and navigation to the other files, which is huge. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

[edit] `@import (reference)` is now implemented in dotless 1.5. Upgrade to that version, and things should start to work.